# Re-attach behavior?

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm trying to change a global setting for Drupal's js. I have this on my callback:

```
$setting['stopWatch']['startTime'] = 4000;
ajax_command_settings($setting, TRUE),
```

I was wondering how I would reattach this behavior after the ajax call is finished. I have this for my js:

```
Drupal.behaviors.stopWatch = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#stopwatch').stopwatch({startTime: settings.stopWatch.startTime}).stopwatch('start');
  }
};
```

Also, I'm not sure why `startTime` isn't available in settings on `Drupal.behaviors.stopWatch` when I do `ajax_command_settings($setting);` instead.

Comment: Are you sure the settings function is working properly? I've been trying to use it and it's not been working as advertised for me.

Answer (score 1):

This will not add variables to settings. Function `ajax_command_settings()` just creates ajax command, that could be added to commands array. If you want to update settings after view ajax completed you should use something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_ajax_data_alter().
 */
function module_name_tricks_views_ajax_data_alter(&$commands, $view) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') {
    $setting = module_name_get_settings($view);
    $commands[] = ajax_command_settings($setting, TRUE);
  }
}
```